# What is the use of rt.jar file in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we use rt.jar in a java project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091040/why-do-we-use-rt-jar-in-a-java-project)

I am very confused to knowing about rt.jar file.

> What is the role
>   of rt.jar file or use of rt.jar file
>   in java??

Thanks.

Answer (score 57):

`rt.jar` contains all of the compiled class files for the base Java Runtime environment. You should not be **messing** with this jar file.

For MacOS it is called `classes.jar` and located under `/System/Library/Frameworks/<java_version>/Classes` . Same **not messing** with it rule applies there as well :).

http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/05/what-does-rtjar-stand-for-in.html

Comment: I heard that MacOSX doesnt have this file. If so, why?

Comment: It's there in MacOSX under a different name `classes.jar` and it is under `/System/Library/Frameworks/<java_version>/Classes` .

Comment: note - as of java 1.7, apple no longer distributes the jdk. The jdk from Oracle is in a different location /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_xx.jdk and has rt.jar not classes.jar

Comment: Usually you are able to find the jar file at `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar`

Comment: This is a very old answer, but it is still true after all these years. I figured out today.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is already answered here :

- [Why do we use rt.jar file in java project ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091040/why-do-we-use-rt-jar-in-a-java-project)

> Basically, rt.jar contains all of the
>   compiled class files for the base Java
>   Runtime ("rt") Environment. Normally,
>   javac should know the path to this
>   file

Also, a good link on [what happens](http://www.thatsjava.com/java-core-apis/19910/) if we try to include our class file in rt.jar.

Comment: The "what happens" link location (provided in February 2011) is broken (October 2015).

Comment: Tried both Wayback Machine and Google, no luck there