# jar files is not found

Tags: swing, java, sun

from where can i download the jar files of these classes

```
 import com.sun.jmx.snmp.tasks.Task;
 import com.sun.java.swing.Painter;
 import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel;
 import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: findjar.com ot type the "classname jar" on google

Comment: All of those are from `rt.jar` that is included in standard JRE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest place to look for `jar` is:

[find jar](http://www.findjar.com/index.x)

However the classes you mentioned can be found here:

[com.sun.jmx.snmp.tasks.Task](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/jmx/snmp/tasks/Task.java.html)

[com.sun.java.swing.Painter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/java/swing/Painter.java)

[com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/nimbus/NimbusLookAndFeel.java.html)

[com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/org/apache/xpath/internal/operations/String.html)

This is what [Vash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390695/vash) mentioned. All are present in [rt.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073967/what-is-the-use-of-rt-jar-file-in-java). On your system you can find it here: [JDK and JRE File Structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdkfiles.html)

Comment: com.sun.java.swing.Painter com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel are not in rt.jar

Comment: http://srcrr.com/java/oracle/openjdk/6/reference/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/nimbus/NimbusLookAndFeel.html Check this. it should be.

Comment: If u've `jdk` installed, see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdkfiles.html

Answer (score 2):

looks like it [rt.jar](http://www.findjar.com/jar/com.sun/jars/rt.jar.html;jsessionid=67A7B1C9871719034E2E1332C31E3E6A)

Take a look at [findjar](http://www.findjar.com/) helps alot.