# Dynamically retrieve the path of rj.jar (classes.jar in OS X)

Tags: java, jar, jvm

All the base classes of Java are stored in the rt.jar ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073967/what-is-the-use-of-rt-jar-file-in-java#answer-5073991) answer says it's called classes.jar in OS X) file.

I am looking for a ways to create a Java function `public static String pathToRTFile()` that retrieves and returns the full path of this file no matter what OS and what JVM is used. If several JVM's are used I only want to retrieve the location for the JVM that executes the function.

Do you know if there is any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are :

```
package com.tools;

public class RtFileFinder {

    public static String getPath() {
        return Class.class.getResource("Class.class").getPath();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(RtFileFinder.getPath());
    }
}
```