# Buiding hibernate-orm from the source in GitHub

Tags: java, git, hibernate, orm, gradle

I am trying to build the hibernate-orm from the source in GitHub: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm.

I followed the "quickstart" guideline, in the GitHub site:

```
git clone git://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm.git
cd hibernate-orm
./gradlew clean build
The build requires a Java 8 JDK as JAVA_HOME, but will ensure Java 6  compatibility.
```

However, I got the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>
> Build file '/Users/salee/git/hibernate-orm/build.gradle' line: 291
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred configuring project ':hibernate-c3p0'.
>
> A problem occurred configuring project ':hibernate-core'.
>
> Cannot get property 'absolutePath' on null object

Would anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a broken build. In which case, your best option may be to raise an issue in Hibernate's GitHub project and attach the output of

```
./gradlew --stacktrace clean build
```

Alternatively, pull the latest code and try again. It seems unlikely that the build will stay broken for long and it may already have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem. It is because of my Mac environment, where rt.jar is classes.jar: [What is the use of rt.jar file in java? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073967/what-is-the-use-of-rt-jar-file-in-java)

By typing "./gradlew --stacktrace clean build," I found the null error occurs at the line 156 of HibernateBuildPlugin.groovy.

> javaCompileTask.options.bootClasspath = java6Home.runtimeJar.absolutePath

I found that the runtimeJar becomes null, and modified the line to

> javaCompileTask.options.bootClasspath = "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar"

Then,the building of hibernate-orm was successful.