# Java bootstrap class path

Tags: java, jsp, bootclasspath

I am building a web project using java, jsp in netbeans. My project works well.

But today when I compile my web project I am getting the following warning message:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
```

Can any one help me in finding what I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning: \[options\] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816423/warning-options-bootstrap-class-path-not-set-in-conjunction-with-source-1-5)

Answer (score 0):

You are using some classes which were compiled with a lower version of javac. You can refer to this blog post: https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/bootclasspath_older_source. Also here direclt on forum of Netbeans you can got some information on your issue: http://forums.netbeans.org/topic43819.html