# warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7 1 warning

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, classpath, warnings, build.gradle, bootstrap-modal

I get a warning message at Build time in my gradle console:

**warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
1 warning**

How can I fix this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: \[options\] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816423/warning-options-bootstrap-class-path-not-set-in-conjunction-with-source-1-5)

Answer (score 3):

Simply put the following code inside the `buildscript` tag of the project level `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
    options.setBootClasspath("PATH_TO_JAVA_7_JRE/lib/rt.jar")
}
```

Just make sure to replace `PATH_TO_JAVA_7_JRE` with the path to yours.

I've struggled with this issue myself a couple of weeks now and finally come up with a solution, which hopefully works for others as well. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If using Android Studio and no other requirement is set on the version of the JDK maybe you can choose to use the embedded JDK:

- File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> Use embedded JDK (recommended)

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle, try to set:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
```