# Javadoc for the element could not be found

Tags: java, javadoc

I get this message

> Note: The Javadoc for this element could neither be found in the attached source nor the attached Javadoc.

for some of my methods, in this case for `java.util.Scanner.nextInt()`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter the number:");
       int x = keyboard.nextInt();
       System.out.print("The number you entered is " + x);
   }
}
```

I attached the Documentation Zip file `rt.jar` and it is working actually for other methods! Also I'm using `jdk-8-apidocs.zip` as documentation resource. Can anybody tell what the problem is?

Comment: "rt.jar" is the [run-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091040/why-do-we-use-rt-jar-in-a-java-project), you should be able to [attach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289617/eclipse-how-to-link-a-jar-containing-javadocs-source-with-its-binary) the javadoc (but it shouldn't be necessary). What version of Java are you targeting?

Comment: I believe it is 1.8.0-b132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I changed the version of Java Doc to `jdk-7u60-apidocs` and everything work fine.