# How can you use java base class libraries without rt.jar?

Tags: java, jar

From:
[Why do we use rt.jar in a java project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091040/why-do-we-use-rt-jar-in-a-java-project)

I get that you need rt.jar to be able to use a base class library such as java `java.util`.

There is no "rt.jar" in the new java SDK. If I were to have a `.class` file compiled from a `.java` file that uses a library from the java base class libraries such as `java.util`, how would I be able to run it if I can't reference "rt.jar"?

From my understanding when making a runnable jar file you use `classpath` to reference other libraries used in the jar. How can I reference the base class libraries when making a jar now that there is no "rt.jar"?

Comment: When the _Java Platform Module System_ was added in Java 9, the JDK was modularized. There is no `rt.jar` (or `tools.jar`) anymore. The standard Java classes are contained in the "run-time image", which is located in the `lib/modules` file (at least in Java 18 on Windows). You can add your own modules to this file in a custom run-time image using `jlink`.

Comment: But even before Java 9, you never had to add `rt.jar` to the class-path, as it was implicitly on the class-path. This is still true in Java 9+ (though the modules are implicitly on the _module-path_ now, instead of the _class-path_). In other words, for classes in the Java standard library, you don't have to use any special class-path/module-path configurations in order to use them. Just add the necessary imports to your source file.

Comment: @Slaw How does implicit work? Does the jvm automatically make the modules and "rt.jar", for older versions, available to any class or jar file that runs in it?

Comment: @Slaw Eclipse is referencing a jar called "jrt-fs". I am confused because if the base class libraries are implicitly in the modular/class paths why is eclipse explicitly pointing to this jar in the build path? Or Is eclipse just saying that they're there without actually doing anything, like configuring the module-path or class-path(for older versions) to include them?

Comment: Yes, any classes in `rt.jar` (older versions) and the modules in the run-time image (newer versions) are automatically available. As for `jrt-fs.jar`, that is related to the "Java Runtime File System", which is an implementation of `java.nio.file.FileSystemProvider` that provides a way to read the run-time image as if they were part of a file system. The `jrt-fs.jar` is compiled in such a way as to be compatible with Java 8 (JRT was added in Java 9, as part of the module system). This allows **tools** running on Java 8 to inspect the run-time image of JDK versions >= 9.

Comment: To be clear, the classes in `jrt-fs.jar` are _also_ in the run-time image (i.e., in the `modules` file). But those classes are compiled to target the version of the JDK. The `jrt-fs.jar` is just a separate compilation of the same classes but targeted for Java 8, and is specifically for use of tools (such as IDEs) running on Java 8. Code compiled for newer versions of Java cannot be executed by older versions of Java.

Comment: @Slaw So for the "ModulePath" under the libraries tab for the Java Build Path in Eclipse when it shows "JRE System Library", all Eclipse is doing is using the `jrt-fs.jar` to read the "run-time image" in the jdk? Meaning it isn't actually doing anything like including it in the "modulepath", it's just showing the current "Java-SE" and its libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `jmods` folder of your jdk installation - the `.jmod` files contain the modules of the JDK (each contains `.class` and/or `.so` files).

You can use the `bin/jmod` tool to list contents, extract, or create `.jmod` files. If you need to inspect the contents of the `.class` files that correspond to `.java` source files from the JDK, you can extract the `.class` files from these `.jmod` files.
For example, the `java.util` classes are in the `java.base.jmod` module file.